# 2014-02-09T00:00:00+05:30 my date coming in this string format.how can i convert into java.util.date object

Tags: java, date

I am receiving the string in this format "2014-02-09T00:00:00+05:30" then how can i convert into java.util.date object.

```
final String ISO_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz";
dateInString="2014-02-09T00:00:00+05:30";       
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(ISO_FORMAT);
final TimeZone utc =TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
System.out.println(date);
```

I have tried this way.Its giving java.text.ParseException:

Comment: Why do you expect anything else? Your string doesn't match your format.

Comment: I am unable to find the format.even i have tried changing with different formats.

Comment: Do you know what `.SSS` means? Have you read the javadoc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format is wrong, I think your looking for `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX`.
`S` is for millisecondes, you don't need this.

Note that XXX will work with Java 7 (see documentation : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), it's the ISO 8601 time zone format.

With Java 6 you can only use ZZZ but it won't match `+05:30` because ZZZ match RFC 822 time zone format

If you're using Java 6, please refer to this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2202300/1140748

Comment: @Chaitu see my edit, I've linked an interesting answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this format `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"` for more information [Class SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)